Can the Couch be upgraded in any version of Theme Hospital?
I came upon a video about Theme Hospital, and it contained the following two frames:


Note that the font in the speech bubbles looks quite weird, but this may be a compression artifact (however, the rest of the picture and animation seemed normal to me). In the first bubble, the Nurse says:

i.e., "The Couch has been enhanced by the Research Department" — the "...has been enhanced(...)" is the standard text in the game, but as far as I know, the Couch cannot be upgraded. Note that it must be "Couch" in the screenshot: "ch" matches with "Research", the vowels both match with "o" in "Electrolyser" in the other screenshot (but I strongly suspect they can't both be "o" in a family-friendly game) and neither matches "a" nor "e", and finally the capital "C" matches lower-case "c" in "Research".
Recall that there are couches in the Psychiatry Room (not in the Staff Room — these are sofas). Hence my questions:

Can the Couch be upgraded in any official version of the game? Am I wrong, and this isn't the Couch at all?
If not, does anyone know what (modded?) version these two screenshots might have been captured from?

I have experience with PC release (CD way back when and GOG now), and I can't find neither on-line nor inside my GOG copy the repository of all Nurse's speech bubbles. I don't want to link the video in question if it turns out that this comes from some sort of unsavory source, but I can say that the animations looked like actual game footage, so this is not a case of only the speech bubble being edited.

After @galacticninja asked about CorsixTH in the comments, I re-checked, and on their YouTube channel, this footage is used as a throwback to the original release (see the first screenshot at the timestamp here). This led me to the apparent source: this promotional Bullfrog video. There are older uploads of the same footage (cf. this timestamp), although other Bullfrog Theme Hospital media don't have the same issues with the mangled font, so it's hard to say where that came from. However, the first question still stands: was the Couch upgradeable in any released version of the game, and was it a Couch at all in the video?

Can you [edit] your post and add a link to the video? Also, have you checked if this is CorsixTH (re-implementation of Theme Hospital)?

@galacticninja, I though I did - I read about it and figured it wasn't, mainly because the resolution seemed to be too low. But went back and checked with their website, and this pointed me in the right direction. I edited the post accordingly.
